# AngularJS : ui.router not displaying the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i configured the ui.router with xhtml templates. But the configured template is not displaying.

**app.js**

```
ClaimsDB.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");

$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      controller:'InitializeCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/main.xhtml'
  })
     .state('main.home', {
          url: "/home",
          controller: 'ClaimController',
          templateUrl: '/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/tilesView.xhtml'

      })
       .state('main.createClaim', {
          url: "/createClaim",
          controller: 'ClaimController',
          templateUrl: '/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/createClaim.xhtml'
      });
 });
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<body data-ng-app="ClaimsDB" style="margin: 0px; background-color: #EDEDED; z-index: 1000;" popover-close="true" exclude-class="exclude" >
    <div id="processing" style="display: none">
        <img src="/cg510_claimsdb_main/core/images/loading_image.gif" />
    </div>
     <div  ui-view="ui-view"></div> 
</body>
```

**main.xhtml**

```
<div>
<div data-ng-controller="InitializeCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">
    <claims-db-header-tag></claims-db-header-tag>
    <div data-ng-include="'/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/breadCrumb.xhtml'" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;z-index: 100; padding-top: 65px;"></div>
    <div data-ng-show="filterShow" data-ng-include="'/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/filter.xhtml'" style="padding-top: 105px;"></div>

    <div  ui-view="ui-view"></div>  
</div>
```

Can anybody help me on what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have `named views` but as routing is configured as for simple views, so remove `ui-view` name from `ui-view` attribute. Both `ui-view` should be without name.

```
<div  ui-view=""></div>
```

Comment: @Sriraj Glad to know that. Thanks :-)